# Showing list of custom posts of a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom post type `Movie` and a custom taxonomy `Genre` with some terms (like Sci-fi).
I want to create a custom template for show all the movies of a particular genre.

I read that it's just a matter of create a file called `taxonomy-genre.php` with a loop inside. I did it, I navigate to `domain.com/movie/sci-fi` but I get 404 (already tried to flush permalinks).

What is the right way?

```
/*
 * Add Custom post types
 */
function n2_custom_post_types() {

  $types = array(

    array('type'          => 'movie',
          'typePlural'    => 'movies',
          'labelSingle'   => 'Movie',
          'labelPlural'   => 'Movies'
      )

  );

  foreach ($types as $type) {

    $typeSingle = $type['type'];
    $typePlural = $type['typePlural'];
    $labelSingle = $type['labelSingle'];
    $labelPlural = $type['labelPlural'];

    $labels = array(
     //...
    );

    $args = array(
      'labels'        => $labels,
      'description'   => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
      'public'        => true,
      'supports'      => array( 'title', 'author', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes' ),
      'has_archive'   => true,
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'rewrite'       => true
    );

    register_post_type( $typeSingle, $args );

  } // end foreach

}
add_action( 'init', 'n2_custom_post_types' );



/*
 * Add Custom Taxonomies
 */
function n2_custom_taxonomies() {

  $taxonomies = array(

    array(
      'name'   => 'genre',
      'single' => 'Genre',
      'plural' => 'Genres',
      'cpt'    => 'movie' )
  );

  foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {

    $name = $taxonomy['name'];
    $single = $taxonomy['single'];
    $plural = $taxonomy['plural'];
    $cpt = $taxonomy['cpt'];

    $labels = array(
     // ...
    );

    $args = array(
      'labels'            => $labels,
      'hierarchical'      => true,
      'show_ui'           => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( $name, $cpt, $args );

  } //foreach
}
add_action( 'init', 'n2_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*. *doesn't work* can mean a million things

Comment: Update post, check it please

Comment: It seems like a rewrite issue or incorrect values when you registered your custom taxonomy/post type. If you flushed permalinks and still getting 404, post your code for registering your custom post type and taxonomy.

Comment: Already tried permalink flush. Added code.

Comment: You are totally registering your cpt and taxonomy wrong. Recheck the codex on these issues

Comment: Pieter, don't fall in error when you see the "$types = array(...". That's not an error. I don't see errors in my code. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Fred K, Maybe taking a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Source_File) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) does show some as mentioned by Pieter Goosen?!

Comment: You are registering 4 post types and 4 taxonomies and the raltion between them is a total stuff up. :-)

Comment: Guys, in my opinion my code is right. Anyway, I registered the post and taxonomy with standard WP code and I get the same problem. I get 404...

Comment: Someone could tell me where my code is wrong? I checked the official doc and I really can't see! I only created a loop for creating more posts at the same time. Where's the problem?